# GWT MVP and JSF at the same time?

Tags: jsf, gwt, mvp

If I do a GWT application with a **[MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter)**. Can you confirm that I will not have to use JSF? I have understood that JSF is just for MVC application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC and MVP are patterns so they are not aware of any technology such as GWT or JSF. MVP is a variation of MVC.

GWT and JSF are technologies used for browser-based client applications. They have completely separate origins and implementations. The only thing that may relate them is that both aim to offer AJAX-rich browser JavaScript code at the end.

You won't need JSF if you do GWT apps. You may encapsulate GWT application into JSF if you have large JSF application and you want to take advantage of GWT.

Comment: ok, I do not have a lot of experience in these technologies, but I understand perfectly what you said. To understand my case, I would like to give an exemple...but I am looking for some help to validate my architecture. I would have : ONE database, ONE website (only html) and ONE admin (pure js). So it would be possible to do this ? What happen at the server side, one app in JSF and one app in GWT ? Tkx

Comment: server side architecture and implementation should be 90% independent from your choice of GWT or JSF. Both GWT and JSF would require for you to provide some implementation classes to interact with business tier (server) - about 10% or less of development in my estimate. In other words, you should be able to use the same server app for both (given it's Java).

Answer (score 0):

GWT is completly seperate from JSF. Thought you could build a site that uses JSF for some parts and GWT for others.

Comment: Ok, here is exactly what I would like to have...but, I do not know if there is a specific architecture for this. For example, can I do 2 separates applications such as : app1 for the admin (GWT + MVP) and the app2 for the website (JSF + Spring MVC) ? I think I have a more complex vision that necessary but what I want is to benefit to the Spring MVC framework and to also follow Google IO architecture recommendation (using MVP). Tkx a lot,

Comment: 2 different apps - 2 different implementations: this is completely valid approach.

Comment: Ok, but can you help me with these 2 differents implementations ? Do you know, architecturally, what component is used in JAVA/SPRING (I think EJB was a solution for this, but it does not exist in SPRING) that fit my case ?